# Copying string from file to array of structures crashes

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010

This code compiles but crashes while running.

```
typedef struct student{
    char name[ 20 ];
    char last[ 20 ];
    unsigned long int ID;
    char email[ 20 ];
    char BA[ 4 ]; 
} *stu;

stu source[ 20 ];

for( int i=0; i<11 ;i++ )  //copy from file to array
{
    if( fscanf( f1 ,"%s%s%u%s%s", &( source[ i ]->name ), &( source[ i ]->last ), &( source[ i ]->ID ), &( source[ i ]->email ), &( source[ i ]->BA ) ) == EOF );
}
```

this is the code it brings up when it crashes, it stops on this line (the popup windows name is input.c)

```
#ifndef _UNICODE
    *(char *)pointer = (char)ch;  /* stops on this line */
    pointer = (char *)pointer + 1;
```

The error message I get is "Unhandled exception at ... in ...exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xccccccc".

Does anyone know why?

Comment: That's what you get for using pointers recklessly... a pointer is only as good as the thing it points to.

Comment: What's the content of the file? Why that if statement with empty code block?

Comment: "crush while running" means falling in love while trying to catch the bus. The word you are looking for is "crash".

Answer (score 2):

You typed:

```
typedef struct student{...}*stu;
```

It's a pointer to struct, you just declared an array of 20 pointers without anything back, you don't know where these pointers point, most likely not to a valid area of memory.

Declare it this way:

```
struct student source[ 20 ];
```

Or use dynamic allocation, but I guess it isn't necessary in your case.

Comment: @OmerAndrewSanMiguel You are vague, please edit the question to add your attempt and the compiler error.

Comment: It should be `struct student source[20]`, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

**Just remove the '*' before the stu.**

**Explanation :**
You mixed two things. The declaration of your structure by

```
struct student{
   char name[ 20 ];
   char last[ 20 ];
   unsigned long int ID;
   char email[ 20 ];
   char BA[ 4 ]; 
};
```

If your are just making that you should declared a variable like this :

```
struct student var;
```

and the renaming of it :

```
typedef struct student newName;
```

In this case you should declared a variable like this :

```
newName variable;
```

So with your code :

```
typedef struct student{
   char name[ 20 ];
   char last[ 20 ];
   unsigned long int ID;
   char email[ 20 ];
   char BA[ 4 ]; 
} *stu;
```

You have to remove the '*' before stu like this :

```
typedef struct student{
   char name[ 20 ];
   char last[ 20 ];
   unsigned long int ID;
   char email[ 20 ];
   char BA[ 4 ]; 
} stu;
```

And then declared your variable like this :

```
stu source[20];
```